# How to match the pattern like "xxx-xx-xxxx" in order to look for documents with social security numbers using elastic search?

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, lucene

I am looking the way to match the pattern like "xxx-xx-xxxx" in order to look for documents with social security numbers using `elastic search`.

Let’s suppose, in indexed documents, I would like to find all those documents that has social security numbers that matches "xxx-xx-xxxx" pattern.

Sample code for indexing the document:

```
InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream("/home/admin/Downloads/20121221.doc");
      ContentHandler contenthandler = new BodyContentHandler();
      Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
      Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
      parser.parse(is, contenthandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
      }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (is != null) is.close();
    }
```

Sample Code for searching

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilderFullText = null;
queryBuilderFullText = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
                        FilterBuilders.regexpFilter("_all", "^(\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}|XXX-XX-XXXX)$"));
SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder;
            requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch()
                    .setIndices(getDomainIndexId(project))
                    .setTypes(getProjectTypeId(project))
                    .setQuery(queryBuilderFullText);
SearchResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet(ES_TIMEOUT_MS);
            SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
if (hits.getTotalHits() > 0) {
System.out.println(hits.getTotalHits());
 } else {
                return 0l;  
        }
```

I am always getting zero hits even many files should match with the pattern.

Comment: I don't know, but you might want to try again without the anchors `^` and `$`

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks. You are right. My query was wrong. \d or \\d characters and ^ or $ anchors are not supported by elastic search. I could not find your post earlier. Can you please help? Instead of updating this thread I have created another thread after updating the query. Please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942207/pattern-matching-in-elastic-search/27942247#27942247

Comment: @nhahtdh I have created another thread after updating the query. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942207/pattern-matching-in-elastic-search?noredirect=1#comment44281008_27942207